# iPhone SDK deployment target on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm hesitant about Deployment target in xCode.
my question : can my application run on iOS 3, 4, 5, 6 if I select on Deployment target 4.3 ?

I can't test my application on an iPhone because I don't have it but I think the application can only run on IOS 4.3 or later

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 2):

If you use iOS 4.3 as deployment target, that will be the minimum version supported by your app. So, **no, it won't run in iOS 3.0 for instance**.

Also, you'll need to detect features not present in the iOS actually running the app and [program them conditionally](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html).

I'd suggest supporting iOS 5 or better. And definitely forgetting about iOS 3.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. The Deployment Target is the earliest version of iOS that your application will support.

Note, however, that if you use an API call from your current SDK (4.3) that is not present in the 3.0 SDK, your application will crash on devices running iOS 3.0.

So even though you can set the Deployment Target to 3.0, that will not guarantee that your app will work on an iOS 3 device.

See the [Apple Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/15-Configuring_Applications/configuring_applications.html) for more details.

Comment: How much this phrase is useful "Note, however, that if you use an API call from your current SDK (4.3) that is not present in the 3.0 SDK, your application will crash on devices running iOS 3.0"

Comment: @Azdaz I mean that if you're using features present only in the 4.3 SDK, but set your Deployment Target to 3.0, your app will crash on devices running 3.0

Comment: yes yes I understand you, I quote this phrase because it's good for anyone have the same question

Comment: @Azdaz Got it. I thought you were asking for a clarification